# How to use multiple filter selector for GridView?

Tags: yii2

I have two widget filters for GridView - checkbox to show favourite items in table and dropdown for items count per page.

```
<?= \kartik\checkbox\CheckboxX::widget([
    'name' => 'LSearch[favourite]',
    'value' => $lotSearch->favourite,
]) ?>
<?= \nterms\pagesize\PageSize::widget() ?>
```

For working of these two widget I need to set filterSelector property of GridView:

```
'filterSelector' => 'input[name="LSearch[favourite]"]',
'filterSelector' => 'select[name="per-page"]',
```

But I need to do this separately for each widget and filtering works for only one widget, because filterSelector is string property and doesn't accept array. Is there any way to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

This issue has been a concern for a few years, and maybe it's a bug.
Try this, but I'm not sure this work well. You need to modify as you need if this doesn't work well.

#### yii.gridView.js

```
 applyFilter: function () {
        var $grid = $(this), event;
        var settings = gridData[$grid.attr('id')].settings;
        var data = {};
        $.each($(settings.filterSelector).serializeArray(), function () {
            if (data[this.name] === undefined) {
                data[this.name] = this.name.indexOf('[]') === -1 ? this.value : [this.value];
            } else if (typeof data[this.name] === 'object') {
                data[this.name].push(this.value);
            }
        });

        $.each(yii.getQueryParams(settings.filterUrl), function (name, value) {
            if (data[name] === undefined) {
                data[name] = value;
            }
        });

        var pos = settings.filterUrl.indexOf('?');
        var url = pos < 0 ? settings.filterUrl : settings.filterUrl.substring(0, pos);

        $grid.find('form.gridview-filter-form').remove();
        var $form = $('<form action="' + url + '" method="get" class="gridview-filter-form" style="display:none" data-pjax></form>').appendTo($grid);
        $.each(data, function (name, value) {
            if (typeof value === 'object') {
                $.each(value, function (id, value_multi) {
                    $form.append($('<input type="hidden" name="t" value="" />').attr('name', name).val(value_multi));
                });
            } else {
                $form.append($('<input type="hidden" name="t" value="" />').attr('name', name).val(value));
            }
        });
        
        event = $.Event(gridEvents.beforeFilter);
        $grid.trigger(event);
        if (event.result === false) {
            return;
        }

        $form.submit();
        
        $grid.trigger(gridEvents.afterFilter);
    },
```

and make sure to modify your config:

```
'assetManager' => [
     'bundles' => [
          'yii\grid\GridViewAsset' => [
               'sourcePath' => __DIR__ . '/../assets',
          ],
     ],
],
```

[source](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/issues/4431)

Answer (score 0):

If i understand your problem correctly, you want to add 2 custom filters for the Gridview.
If that is correrct you can provide comma separated list in the `filterSelector` property and all those filters will work correctly, currently what you are doing is overriding the property declared first and only the last one applies.

Another thing is that you are not using the searchModel object to populate the inputs as that would load the value from the checkbox/dropdown to the model and set it into the respective inputs too after the gridview is loaded.

Since your current problem is how to assign multiple filters so i am not addressing the searchmodel related inputs.

Change your code to below in GridView

```
"filterSelector" => 'input[name="LSearch[favourite]"],select[name="per-page"]',
```

I am using the same approach

[image]